# Certificate issue on remote desktop

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, certificate

see the below link:
[Certificate issue on remote desktop](http://www.faultwire.com/solutions-Windows_7/Remote-Desktop-Connection-*1368.HTML)

I have 2 PCs with Windows 7 Ultimate. Both are in `NETHOME`, and are connected with a crossover cable.

PC 1: computer name = `alfa` -> (main PC) , IP = `192.168.0.1`
PC 2: computer name = `beta-lap` ->(laptop) , IP = `192.168.0.2`

When I want to remote in to one of these PCs from the other, I get this error:

```
Full Title :  
Remote Desktop Connection    
Body Text :  
The remote computer could not be authenticated due to problems with its security certificate. It may be unsafe to proceed.

Certificate name

Name in the certificate from the remote computer:

blablabla

Certificate errors

The following errors were encountered while validating the remote computer's certificate:

The certificate is not from a trusted certifying authority.

Do you want to connect despite these certificate errors? [Yes] [No]

[ ] Don't ask me again for connections to this computer
```

I can bypass it by checking "connect despite these certificate errors", and can then view the remote computer. But is this normal?

Also, there is an attention icon on the network connection icon in each computer's system tray. What is the problem with this little network?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this normal -

Yes it is, Windows Vista/2008+ secures the remote connection with a self signed certificate. This certificate only exists on the server and until you import it on your machine, you will get a warning.

How to fix -

You can view the certificate then import it to your local store and it will be trusted.

The reason for this is simply in a large corporate environment, with their own certificate authority, they can give every machine a certificate, and, as the root will be trusted, all computers will "know" each other automatically.

as for the attention icons, I can't help you here - this sounds like you have networking issues on your machine (local only/no internet etc.) and that is a completely separate question that I need more information on to help you with.

Comment: really thanks for answer / which information do you need for my network issue ?

Comment: and why remote connection still works with this network issue ?

Comment: Again, need to know more about your network - probably means local only/no internet.

Comment: which features should i tell you about this little network ? / just 2 pc with windows 7! besides there is no internet here!

Comment: Which is why you are probably getting the yellow triangles! Double click on one and see what it says!

Answer (score 4):

The suggestions above "just check the box" completely breaks the chain of trust. This is especially important in any enclave that represents a Point of Sales (POS) environment. It is the application supplier legal responsibility "Due Care" to engineer that completed chain of trust pedigree. There are several available exploits that takes advantage of a broken chain of trust.
An POS Audit should identify shortfalls such as this. Hopefully the supplier will take corrective action and complete that required chain of trust.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow Wil's answer and fix it, but since you know you are connecting to a computer you KNOW is safe, you can check the box to ignore the certificate.

The certificate is just designed to make sure you can trust the host you are connecting to (whether with Remote Desktop, as in this case, or a web site using HTTPS), and you know you can trust it in this case since it is your computer.

You can import the certificate, but why bother "fixing" this when you can just check the box, and move on?

Comment: I am a long-time professional IT guy, and I use RDP all the time, and I have NEVER once not just checked the box, but I have never connected to a server I do not know either. After all, who is going to give you RDP access to a server you DON'T know, unless you are a hacker?

Comment: thanks for answer / both computers are mine bro / there is no hacker here :)

Comment: @LostLord I TOTALLY realized they are both yours, otherwise, I might not recommend just checking the box.

Comment: i installed both certificate on both machines in trusted ... / but still have attention icon! this is my reason to fix that certificate error , not bypass!

Comment: @LostLord Try installing into your personal store, not the trusted store, but I am saying you SHOULD bypass it since it is not worth fixing somthing that is not broken. P.S. something that was pointed out to me yesterday, if you go @kcotreau, it will end up in my responses when I click on my user link.